# GET https://ipinfo.io/ 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geocoding

I'm having a small issue with getting data from a API. I get the error "GET https://ipinfo.io/ 401 (Unauthorized)". Relevant code:

```
$.getJSON('//ipinfo.io', function(response){
      console.log(response.loc)
      var latlngIP = location['loc'].split(',');
      var latIP    = latlngIP[0];
      var lngIP    = lnglngIP[1];
```

API: https://ipinfo.io/

I did not exceed the 1000 uses per day limit.

EDIT:before you suggest it, adding https or http did not fix it.

Comment: I got 401 when using https but it worked for me using http.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nergmerdle/Lhdfz39L/

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a 401 for https if you do not have an access token. See https://ipinfo.io/pricing

EDIT: HTTPS access is now free: https://twitter.com/ipinfoio/status/779374440417103872

Comment: When you signup for a paid plan you'll get sent full instructions.